# Ubuntu 14.04 not connecting to wifi

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, lenovo, realtek-wireless

I just bought a lenovo ideapad and installed 14.04lts. Currently it shows the wi-fi icon as trying to connect but a few second later it shows the alert that I have been disconnected. Can anyone help? Is there any set of drivers or other software that I need to install?

My current wireless card is: Realtek Semiconductor CO.,ltd RTL8723BE PCIe wireless Network Adapter

Comment: If you walk the computer over very close to the router, say one meter, does it connect?

Answer (score 0):

This device is known for that. Lets try:

```
echo "options rtl8723be swenc=1 fwlps=0 ips=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
echo 'KERNEL=="wlan0", RUN+="/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 txpower 18"' | sudo tee -a /etc/udev/rules.d/75-wlan.rules
```

Reboot

Answer (score 0):

I have a lenovo y50 with the same card and I constantly keep running into the same problem.

The following command always helps me fix that.

```
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
sudo reboot
```